# One-Way SSH Lag

Tags: ssh

I am on a LAN with two hosts connected to a router. One host connects to the router via an ethernet cable (`host1`), while the other connects to the router via WiFi (`host2`). `host1` is running Arch Linux, while `host2` is running Ubuntu 15.10.

**Strange Occurrence:** When I SSH from `host2` into `host1`, I experience no lag. But when I SSH from `host1` into `host2`, I experience a lot of SSH lag. Typing in ViM is unbearable as characters are delayed for so long it blocks my train of thought :(.

What on earth could explain this, especially given that `host1` has the faster connection?

Comment: Is there any packet loss? Did you try using wireshark/tcpdump ?